# python: validating BST

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to fix my solution to check if a tree is a binary search tree:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Solution:
    def isValidBST(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: bool
        """

        if root == None or root.left == None and root.right == None:
            return True

        if root:
            if root.left != None and root.val > root.left.val:
                out = self.isValidBST(root.left)
                return True
            elif root.right != None and root.val < root.right.val:
                out = self.isValidBST(root.right)
                return True
            else:
                return False


        return False

s = Solution()
s.isValidBST([0,null,3,1])
```

However, I'm not quite sure what to do when I encounter a null value that seems to cause it to return the wrong validation.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense for `Solution` to be its own class.  Surely being valid is a property of the tree itself.  Furthermore, you don't actually build a tree anywhere in this code, nor do you have any code for turning a list into a tree, or treating a list as if it was a tree.

Answer (score 0):

reverse your logic, check if left is bigger than root then return false, same with right if right less than. In the case left is null or right it's still true so travese and continue checking

```
if root.left != None and root.val < root.left.val:
        return False
elif root.right != None and root.val > root.right.val:
            return False
else
#traverse left,right
return true
```